# index.php page not working with slim framwork api in share hosting

Tags: php, slim

I have created a slim project in godaddy. after creation, I verify everything works by going to pctechtips.org/apps/slimpro/public and I get the slim webpage. the default index.php inside public directory contaings some code to display that page. when I remove the code and replace it with mine. It doesn't display anything. what is wrong?
default slim install index.php

```
<?php
if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli-server') {
    // To help the built-in PHP dev server, check if the request was actually for
    // something which should probably be served as a static file
    $url  = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $file = __DIR__ . $url['path'];
    if (is_file($file)) {
        return false;
    }
}

require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

session_start();

// Instantiate the app
$settings = require __DIR__ . '/../src/settings.php';
$app = new \Slim\App($settings);

// Set up dependencies
require __DIR__ . '/../src/dependencies.php';

// Register middleware
require __DIR__ . '/../src/middleware.php';

// Register routes
require __DIR__ . '/../src/routes.php';

// Run app
$app->run();
```

my index.php page

```
<?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\App;
$app->get('/hello/{name}', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
    $name = $args['name'];
    $response->getBody()->write("Hello, $name");

    return $response;
});
$app->run();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I Think the problem here is about the path of composer auto load file 
Its not correct to be in  the public directory

In default index.php

```
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

In your code

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

Comment: I forgot to mention I included all paths from original file into new file...still doesn't work

Comment: Please share the error log data from your web server